# Upgrade Angular Material from 13 to 14

Tags: angular-material, angular14, angular14upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my Angular application that uses material from Angular 13 (13.1.0) to 14 (14.0.1). I am using steps provided at https://update.angular.io/?v=13.0-14.0.

My Angular and CLI versions upgraded successfully but getting following error while upgrading Material:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of today, flex-layout was not updated to support Angular 14 (see [this git issue](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1404)). So either you can wait until it does, or try updating with the `--force` flag and hope that everything works.